# Split string returns character null

Tags: java, string

I would that my split doesn't contain null characters .

```
boolean a = false  ;
boolean aggiunto = false ;
boolean trovato = false ;
String elemento = null ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
String stringa = null;
HashSet<String> totale = new HashSet <String> () ;

Vector<String> subtag = new Vector<String> () ;
stringa += line ;

String []stringasplittata = null ;

String s = "s" ;
if (line.startsWith(s))
{


    stringasplittata= stringa.split("//s//-1",-1);
    for (int i = stringasplittata.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    {

        System.out.println(stringasplittata[i]);

        if (stringasplittata[i].equals("s"))
        {
            System.out.println(stringasplittata[i+2] ) ;
            subtag.add(stringasplittata[i+1] );
        }
    }

    System.out.println(subtag.size());
}
```

if I insert :

s panasonic -1

my output is :

nulls panasonic -1

Comment: `String stringa = null ; ` is the culprit. Change it to `String stringa = ""; `

Comment: why limit split with -1 ?

Comment: @PhilippSander - He might be having leading and trailing whitespaces Or he doesn't know what `-1` actually does.

Comment: And what is the reult you expacted?

Comment: Shouldn't the regular expression be `"\\s\\-1"`?

Comment: I resolved but I have another problem.Why doesn't matches :   if (stringasplittata[i].equals("s"))

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You cannot do any operation if your string value is null. So before using stringa.split(), use null check.